# Angular libraries that share the same element property name

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap

I attempted to Google and find a solution to this, but couldn't find it.  If I have two libraries that share the same property name in the element, it seems one attaches to the other and throws errors because of that.

In this case I'm using @ng-select/ng-select and ngx-bootstrap/typeahead.

Both use `[typeahead]` property.  It seems ngx-bootstrap/typeahead is attaching ng-select's element, and when I use that element's control, it throws an error, because I believe ngx-bootstrap/typeahead is expecting a different result.  How can I go about still using both controls even though they share the same property name?

Comment: are the 2 libs imported into modules. If so, instead of importing them at root level import only the one you need into the module you are using it in. Then it will know which one you are referring to.

Comment: The controls are needed on the same page, so I assume no matter which way I slice it, it will come down to one module.